# How do I free a singly liked list and assign the head node to `NULL`?

Tags: c, function, singly-linked-list

I am trying to write a function that will free a singly linked list and assign the head node to `NULL`
Here is my code:

The structure of the list.

```
typedef struct Node {
    int n;
    struct Node *next;
} list;
```

The function:

```
void free_list(list **head)
{
        list *aux;
        list *ptr = *head;

        while (ptr)
        {
                aux = ptr->next;
                free(ptr);
                ptr = aux;
        }
        *head = NULL;
}
```

But does this assign the head to `NULL` after freeing the linked list? How can I check if it is set to `NULL`?

Comment: Yes, it does, to check it use `printf("head is NULL = %s\n", head == NULL ? "yes" : "no");` just after calling `free_list()`

Comment: Show the calling code where `free_list` is called. Your answer will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Making multiple copies of variables' data only serves to complicate what's happening.

When you want to free the nodes of a linked list, you will have a line that looks like this:

```
head = free_list( head ); // return nodes to the heap
```

and then a very simple function like this:

```
list *free_list( list *head ) {
    while( head ) {
        list *del = head;
        head = head->next;
        free( del );
    }
    return head;
}
```

This will work even if the list was empty when the function is called.

(A node is not a list. It may the the entry point to a series of nodes, but it is not a list. Perhaps `list` should be called `list_item` because it is a singular, not a collective.)

Comment: That's quite arguable, with your version it is easy to forget to assign the return value of the function, i.e. `free_list( head );` instead `head = free_list( head );`

Comment: While that is true, it is important, also, to acknowledge in the calling code that `head` is perhaps somehow changed by the function. It may only be personal preference. Double pointers are a source of many bugs. Some say tomato and some say tomato.

Comment: True! but the difference is that with a good warning level the compiler can detect bugs in the OPs version with double pointers, while your version can only be protected with extensions like `___attribute__ ((warn_unused_result))`

Comment: One can use either method. I favour my version because they are called 'functions' not 'subroutines'. All good... :-) (But I wonder why Dennis Ritchie chose `strcat( char *...` over `strcat( char **`... Hmmm...)

Comment: Bad example, Ritchie himself admitted hundreds of times that they didn't build C with safety in mind :) but well, I just wanted to make clear that the OP's version is quite correct.

Comment: @DavidRanieri (Missed addressing last reply to you. Sorry.) Look at the OP question. That version is declared 'void'... The question is, "How can I check..." My suggestion makes that checking self-evident, imho...

Comment: @Fe2O3 Yes, you code works. But I want to pass the head node as a double pointer, as in my code above. I have 2 questions, 1.Do double pointers make my code complicated? 2. Why should I use a single pointer? Are there cases where single pointer has an edge over double pointers?

Comment: @LeuelAsfaw Complicated? Your version has 2 single ptrs and 1 double ptr in scope for the entire function. My version has 1 single ptr in scope for the function, and another that winks in-and-out for a moment. You decide. Q2: Recent questions from learners: "What does `*(*(ptr+1))` mean?" Given that code is written once and read 100 times, I believe "simplicity is best". I believe my version is 'simpler' and easier to understand at a glance.

Comment: @LeuelAsfaw Looking at your code again. Why did you dereference **head at the beginning, then wait until the end of the function to assign *head = NULL? Yeah... Simplicity is the answer. :-) You write " But I want to pass..." Why? What advantage does passing a double pointer bring? It has to be "unpacked" somewhere/ somehow.